# what is the reason of Invalid Address specified to RtlFreeHeap

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

the develop environment is vs2008, the language is c++, when I release the problem,at beginning it run with out problem but after several minutes it stop and show error like that : HEAP[guessModel.exe]: Invalid Address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 003E0000, 7D7C737B ).
who can tell me the reason of the error. thank you very much.

Comment: you would need to show some code in order for us to help you further however often in such cases as the one you describe it could basically be anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to use the wild pointer. Either the pointer to the memory which got freed has been de-referenced or some invalid pointer has been passed to free function.

It is very hard to tell the reason without seeing the actual code. You can attach some debugging tools like WinDbg and get the cause for this error.

Comment: Sorry. In that case you probably have to post minimal code in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

Its because your heap has become corrupt. You probably are either freeing memory twice or using some uninitialized pointer or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was next:

- By mistake in my sources was used two classes with the same name
- One class was hidden into CPP , other had normal view header and CPP implementation.
- It was compilled without error but in some case segmentation fault signal was appeared)